# Submit Google Custom Search

Tags: php, forms, submit, google-custom-search

Im using old Google custom search code that not working anymore and I would like to check how I can fix the code to working with the new Google custom search.

I tried many things with no luck, this is the code I have today:

```
// Google Search (deprecated - to remove)
if ($task == 'search' && $params->get('googleSearch'))
{
    $language = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $lang = $language->getTag();
    // Fallback to the new container ID without breaking things
    $googleSearchContainerID = trim($params->get('googleSearchContainer', 'k2GoogleSearchContainer'));
    if($googleSearchContainerID == 'k2Container'){
        $googleSearchContainerID = 'k2GoogleSearchContainer';
    }
    $document->addScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi');
    $document->addScriptDeclaration('
        google.load("search", "1", {"language" : "'.$lang.'"});
        function OnLoad(){
            var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();
            var siteSearch = new google.search.WebSearch();
            siteSearch.setUserDefinedLabel("'.$application->getCfg('sitename').'");
            siteSearch.setUserDefinedClassSuffix("k2");
            options = new google.search.SearcherOptions();
            options.setExpandMode(google.search.SearchControl.EXPAND_MODE_OPEN);
            siteSearch.setSiteRestriction("'.JURI::root().'");
            searchControl.addSearcher(siteSearch, options);
            searchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET);
            searchControl.setLinkTarget(google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_SELF);
            searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("'.$googleSearchContainerID.'"));
            searchControl.execute("'.JRequest::getString('searchword').'");
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

The current Custom Search element API documentation can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

Comment: thank you Andy, I know that but I trying update my code with the new google code

Answer (score 0):

Update your Old system to New. it is Easy to use.

Follow this link;
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse

then click on this 
Control Panel
with this link: https://cse.google.com/create/new
after create Use this following`enter code here` code in your website:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '012345678901234567890:inyoqlhp8ya'; /* 21 Numbers code */
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```